# adding classpath of an external file(updated values) to a config file of web application

Tags: java, classpath, war

How do I add and make mulitiple external config files override default ones?

I tried it in different ways by using `propertiesLoaderUtils` and `resources.properties`, but it doesn't work. Please suggest me a way to add the classpath of the external file which contains an updated values to the war file.